# JavaScript の&とはなんでしょうか

Tags: javascript, node.js

条件式内でこの様に&が記述がされております。

```
if (val & 0x400000) return val
```

&&の意味はわかっておりますが&単体は調べてもわかりませんでした。
どういう意味なのかご解説いただけますでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators
ビットごとの論理積です。この場合 `val` には整数値が入っているはずで、その値のビット22が0か1かの判別をしています。

Answer (score 1):

0x400000を２進数にすると0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000となります。この１のビットが立っていたらvalを返す。という意味になります。